# Is there a way to make the insert not fail if one record fails?

Tags: apex, dml

I am inserting multiple records using Apex DML; e.g.

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

// Populate the accounts list

insert accounts;
```

If there is any kind of error inserting any of the records, the insert fails for the entire batch. Is there a way to make the insert not fail if one record fails?

Comment: Question was asked on the [Salesforce IRC channel](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/01/back-to-the-old-skool-with-the-salesforce-irc-channel.html) - too good not to post here!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a DML database method with a value of `false` for the optional `opt_allOrNone` parameter - i.e.

```
Database.SaveResult[] result = Database.Insert(accounts, false);
```

From [the docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml.htm),

> Use DML database methods if you want to allow partial success of a
>   bulk DML operation—if a record fails, the remainder of the DML
>   operation can still succeed. Your application can then inspect the
>   rejected records and possibly retry the operation. When using this
>   form, you can write code that never throws DML exception errors.
>   Instead, your code can use the appropriate results array to judge
>   success or failure. Note that DML database methods also include a
>   syntax that supports thrown exceptions, similar to DML statements.

Comment: Also, using the optional allOrNone parameter will allow the remainder of the operation to succeed.  Database.insert(accounts, false); see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm

Comment: @DerekLansing good catch, thanks! Edited my answer

Comment: However if a trigger throws an unhandled exception it will mark all objects in that trigger context as failed.

Comment: @ca_peterson Moral of the story: catch your exceptions :-)

Comment: @metadaddy Gr8 post! I have a question. How do I capture those records that failed to get inserted?

Comment: @metadaddy that link is dead, know anyone on the doc team who can resurrect it? see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104698/links-to-documentation-for-database-dml-method-gone-from-apex-docs/104701#104701

Comment: @ca_peterson that link is dead, know anyone on the doc team who can resurrect it? see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104698/links-to-documentation-for-database-dml-method-gone-from-apex-docs/104701#104701

Comment: All the docs URLs changed (I've been begging for permalinks for a while), but the current source seems to be [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm%23apex_System_Database_methods). See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/104901/60 for why.