# Links to Documentation for Database.* DML Method? Gone from APEX Docs

Tags: apex, dml, database

So we've got the usual DML statements `insert accts;` and we've got the database class dml statements, e.g. `Database.insert(accts, false)`. Had a team member ask me a question about the parameter definitions and when I looked for the documentation it seems to have completely disappeared. Anyone know where to find it? Any links to the old html documentation out there that still might have this?

Dug through the apex docs, developer force, and stack exchange. No dice, found an old link in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/53680/594), but now it's dead.

Comment: Are you looking for [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm%23apex_methods_system_database)?

Comment: here is the document. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm%23apex_System_Database_methods

Comment: Those both just resolve to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/

Comment: Look out for the %23 in your SFDC documentation URL when you're sharing it with anyone. For some reason SFDC is URL encoding the # character (usually used for an anchor) which is causing the URL to not be correct. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation exists in the most literal interpretation of the "correct" location. The `Database.insert` method and friends are actually part of the `Database` *class* in the `System` namespace, and not a part of the `Database` namespace.

As such, the documentation is found at *Reference > System Namespace > Database Class*, or directly at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm%23apex_System_Database_methods

Comment: i thought i was losing my mind, thanks @ca_peterson!

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

They do exist, just in a strange location. See @ca_peterson's answer below

#### Old Answer

For unknown reasons there isn't a place for the specific method documentation. However there are other places to look to get the details you need, primarily 
the slew of classes found under the [Database Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Database.htm), not the DML namespace.

For example from the [SaveResult Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult)

> It inserts two accounts using `Database.insert` with a false second parameter to allow partial processing of records on failure.

From historical knowledge, I know that's the opt_AllOrNone parameter, which also exists in with the [DML Options class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm#apex_Database_DmlOptions_optAllOrNone) so you can use that to get an actual description. Bear in mind, the default is `true` when used with `Database.` unlike `DMLOptions` - exactly the reason why it would be good to have this sort of documentation (see this excellent [blog post](http://www.eltoro.it/ArticleViewer?id=a07A000000PyGjkIAF) from Andres Perez for details on confirming this behavior)

> optAllOrNone
>
> Specifies whether the operation allows for partial success. Signature
>
> public Boolean optAllOrNone {get; set;}
>
> Property Value
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Usage
>
> If optAllOrNone is set to true, all changes are rolled back if any
>   record causes errors. The default for this property is false and
>   successfully processed records are committed while records with errors
>   aren't.
>
> This property is available in Apex saved against Salesforce API
>   version 20.0 and later.

Comment: Great minds think alike.

Comment: At times it seems like there's very little rhyme or reason as to how those classes are laid out in the documentation. One can easily miss some very important classes, or classes that should be located adjacent to one another because they're functionally equivalent or so closely related. These two would be good examples.

Comment: Not to mention, every time they change their docs, the URL structure changes and they don't even bother to re-write URLS.  Half my SF bookmarks are dead.  You come across dead links constantly on SE and even more so on their own developer forums...

Comment: @crmprogdev yep, that's where i was looking, there isn't any documentation for the Database.<method> calls, in particular the method signature outside of the tangential documentation in the return types, e.g. Database.SaveResult, there used to be a page for this I swear that documented the actual method signature

Comment: @crmprogdev you'll notice that they have some explanation buried in the example for save results that the second param when false allows for partial success. but was looking for specific documentation like they have for each of the attributes of the save result. seems like i didn't miss it, it just no longer has it's own section ...

Comment: I think you're looking for the [DML Options Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm%23apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions?search_text=order%20of%20execution) which includes the All or None.

Comment: yeah, good point that at least has the same param name, was mainly hoping to confirm that specific documentation doesn't exist which i think we've done (and thanks for providing all the hidden places to find this)

Comment: No problem. It seems as though I "live" in those docs these days searching for little nuggets of enlightenment while trying to write code. It's difficult enough to find what one needs without having it hidden away in some obscure location after being obfuscated when originally written. (sigh) Searching for what one wants is a challenge with the new UI.